# Текст на андроиде не розтягивается на ширину блока

Tags: android

Для моб стоит ограничение по ширине:
     [@media](/users/3055/mediaportal) screen and (max-device-width: 640px) {
      body { min-width:640px; } 
    }
На андроиде на экране 320пх текст занимает размер ширины экрана и справа от текста остается пустая область 320пх которая не влазит на viewport телефона (если прокручивать скролл вправо).

Comment: Вы можете уточнить, какие технологии используете?

Comment: media queries